# Проблема десериализации сообщений debezium в .net5

Tags: .net, postgresql, .net-5

Всем привет, пытаюсь консьюмить сообщения из топика, которые продьюсит Debezium. Прилетают сообщения формата:

> "\0\0\0\0F\0\u0002\u0002\u0002\nApple\u00161.4.2.Final\u0014postgresql\u0018Cdc_Testʽ���^\0\btrue\u0018Cdc_Test\fpublic\u000etestcdc\u0002���\u0001\u0002����\u0005\0\u0002r\u0002н���^\0"

- Проверял на коннекторах decoderbufs и wal2json
- database encode - utf8
- version - PostgreSQL 12.6 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu

Подскажите пожалуйста, каким десериализатором на .NET 5 можно расколдовать?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Десериализация сообщения debezium в .net](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1328523/%d0%94%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-debezium-%d0%b2-net)

Comment: да, его почему-то закрыли, проблема так и не решена (